# how to split file on the basis of every 100th numbers of blank line

Tags: shell

I have file which has some commands separated by blank lines. I want to split file into number of files on the basis of every 100th blank lines so that I  can execute files in parallel.

File :

```
create table..;

create index..;

alter index...;

create index ...;
```

I want to make 2 files like, I should have to control on blank lines :
File01 :

```
create table..;

create index..;
```

File02 :

```
alter index...;

create index ...;
```

Regards,